# Approach to Using Multiple Database Versions

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I have an WPF app that I am designing in c# that I need to connect to multiple versions of the same database and have the program work. I don't need to connect to more than one version at a time, but I'm looking for an approach that doesn't require me to write 5-10 different data layers.

If I have a `widgetV1`, `widgetV2`, etc. object and I would like to "GetWidget"... I'm not so happy about having to write "GetWidgetV1", "GetWidgetV2", etc. functions. This could get really tiresome if I have to write the same code for 5-10 versions, over and over again... for every object in the database.

The tables are only slightly different, there might be a few more columns in one than the other. There may be some type differences there.

WidgetV1 could have Prop1, Prop2, PropC
WidgetV2 could have Prop1, Prop3, ProcC, PropD

So some properties will be the same, but others will be different.

I've started an approach using generics where I can do a get, add, remove, etc by passing in the type - `widget1`, `widget2`, etc. But I still have to have the actual types and have to choose the type based on what version I've determined that I am connected to.

I have no issues on the front end, I take whatever version of the object I have and convert it to a DTO and it all looks the same there, but it's the data access that I feel like I'm going to have to duplicate many times over.

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider writing a class (maybe a base class) called WidgetRepository, which has a `GetWidge()` method. `WidgetRepository` would have its database access parameterized in some way, so you can create a `WidgetRepository` to access one or another version of the database. Then you just pass that around, and the consumers of the widgets don't know or care about the DB version. They just ask their friendly widget provider for a widget, and *all of the details about the database* are hidden inside `WidgetRepository`.

Comment: You should remove the WPF tag, which is irrelevant and add a tag telling which technology you use for communicating with your database. And then add some example code.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I actually have a `WidgetRepository` with a `GetWidget` method... but what I'm talking about is in that method I have figure out if this is `WidgetV1`, `WidgetV3`, `WidgetV5` and then write a separate data access function/method to get that particular `Widget`.

Comment: @PalleDue I'm looking for ideas about what technology would be best to use. Right now I'm using Entity Framework, but there is probably something better.

Comment: @BarryFranklin Are you saying that at runtime, any given widget access may come up with a different version of the widget? I call GetWidget() three times in a row and the first call gets V3, second call gets V5, third call gets V2?

Comment: @BarryFranklin It would also be helpful if you could show code illustrating in what ways the different widget versions differ.

Comment: @EdPlunkett No, connect to a version of the DB. ONLY get one type of widget from there on. User can then disconnect and connect to a different version of the database and get a different version of the widget.

Comment: you can customize EF DbContext based on connection string with fluent api. besides, your best friends are polymorphism and reflection

Comment: @BarryFranklin So if it's EF, you've got multiple different classes... Maybe you need to write a Widget POCO class and have the repository translate between that and the EF classes?

Comment: Call me crazy, but maybe this problem is one more simply addressed in a dynamically typed language. Otherwise you'll need side by side versions of the same model  (or at least an inheritance scheme replicated across all models requiring compile-time knowledge of the difference between model versions) with their own data access methods depending on how you're updating, querying, etc. You could put many patterns around that but at the end of the day dynamically typed languages handle dynamic types better than statically typed languages do.

Comment: @S.C. Well, if I knew anything about a dynamically typed language I might try it, but sadly I don't. The side-by-side models is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @TakeMeAsAGuest Is there a way to define a class with the fluent API that will allow for properties that don't correspond to any column in a table? If I try to map a property to a column that doesn't exist, is it just going to blow up?

Comment: You could make use of C#'s `dynamic/ExpandoObject` type for this to more easily enumerate members when serializing to and from the database but any business logic you need to perform on those objects will become very messy.

Comment: If you put all of your business logic into stored procedures that are versioned automatically with your database schemas and your front-end is already generic, that just leaves your controllers that need to handle unknown model definitions. They can certainly do that with `dynamic/ExpandoObject` if you're willing to dynamically call stored procedures with as many properties as they have, for instance. Deserialization would be easy that way and serialization could be looped over for parameter generation. C# would turn into a middle man with no significant business logic but that could work.

Comment: @S.C. These databases are not under my control. I cannot use stored procedures.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I just wrote up an answer based on that which would have greatly simplified things. Alternatively, you can place your controllers and models in a different assembly from your front-end and place a dedicated controller in between that loads up the version of your backend that matches the version of your database. That way your duplication is replaced with versioning again.